# It is possible to show a dialog once per month in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have a simple dialog that should be shown if there is a new version of `.apk`. The problem is that it shows every time the `onResume()` method is called.
I was wondering if it is possible to only show this dialog once per month.

Below is the code of the `Dialog` and the condition which tells me if there is a new `.apk`.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new getVersionName(getApplicationContext()).execute();
} 

public class getVersionName extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Context mContext;

    getVersionName(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }
    //Compare with the online version

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

        //  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String path ="http://test.com/AndroidApp/test.txt";
        URL u = null;

        try {
            u = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
            bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.
            String getVersion = bo.toString().substring(12, 17);
            String getVersionFromUrl = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            if (!getVersionFromUrl.equals(getVersion)) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder1.setMessage("It is a new version of this app");
                        builder1.setCancelable(true);
                        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                "Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        int permissionExternalMemory = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                                        String url = "http://test.com/AndroidApp/test.v1.0.3.apk";
                                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                                        String getUrl = url.substring(34, 55);
                                        request.setTitle(getUrl);
                                        getMimeType(getUrl);

                                        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                                        if (permissionExternalMemory != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                                    MainActivity.this,
                                                    STORAGE_PERMISSIONS,
                                                    1
                                            );

                                        }

                                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, getUrl);
                                        manager.enqueue(request);
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                "No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        builder1.show();

                    }
                });

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("YourApp", "Well that didn't work out so well...");
            Log.e("YourApp", e.getMessage());

        }
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // mContext.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to store the date the dailog is displayed, then each time the app opens you will have to check if a month has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer had the right idea but is executed incorrectly as it will not work after the last month in the year!

You could test to see if a month (30 days) has passed using the following method:

```
public boolean hasMonthPassed() {
    long lastTimestamp = prefs.getLong("myPreferenceKey", 0);
    long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (currentTimestamp - lastTimestamp) >= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30);
}
```

You can then use this in your class elsewhere:

```
if(hasMonthPassed()) {

    // Your code here

    // Set the preference
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("myPreferenceKey", System.currentTimeMillis());
    editor.apply()
}
```

Alternatively, the previous answer can be fixed by updating as follows:

```
int storedMonth = prefs.getInt("myPreferenceKey", 0);
int currentMonth = LocalDate.now().getMonth().getValue();

if (storedMonth < currentMonth || (storedMonth == Month.DECEMBER.getValue() && currentMonth != Month.DECEMBER.getValue())) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("myPreferenceKey", currentMonth);
    editor.apply();

}
```

Comment: @EdGoerge Where is the difference between `pref` and `prefs` ?
Can you define more for `SharedPreferences` something ?

Comment: @Spritzig that's a typo - will update the answer. `prefs` refers to whatever variable your `SharedPreferences` instance is